# Уникальные фрагменты в back stage

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment-manager

Есть 3 фрагмента: **A**, **B**, **C**.

Добавляю в back stack по очереди **A**, **B**, **C** через метод `add();`
После этого добавляю еще раз фрагмент **A** и получаю такой stack: **A**, **B**, **C**, **A**.

Как добиться того, что б при добавлении **A**, он пропадал из stack и добавлялся сверху?

Пробовал перед добавлением искать его через метод `findFragmentByTag()`, а потом удалять через `remove()`, но это не приводит к нужному результату. Фрагмент теряет видимость, но из стека не пропадает.